# MySQL: Safe to kill transaction that is stuck in "Waiting for table metadata lock"

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6, locking, deadlock

Good morning/afternoon/night.

I attempted to add a column to a table with a good few million rows. Here is the full query:

```
alter table date_tasks_mark add column noDuplicate int unsigned not null default 0
```

However it seems to be stuck.

```
| 28893 | root         | localhost | database_name   | Query   | 10668 | Waiting for table metadata lock | alter table date_tasks_marks add column noDuplicate int unsigned not null default 0
```

Is it safe for me to kill the query or will it corrupt my table (it has been in this state for about a half hour)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. Your `alter table` query hasn't even started.
However, the `waiting for table metadata lock` means, that there's another transaction operating on that table for a long time and you should rather kill that one to solve the problem. (read more about it here: [8.11.4 Metadata Locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/metadata-locking.html))

To find this transaction, this thread is probably helpful: [How do I find which transaction is causing a “Waiting for table metadata lock” state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148630/how-do-i-find-which-transaction-is-causing-a-waiting-for-table-metadata-lock-s)